# Select those records which have their foreign occur multiple times in an other table

Tags: sql

I've a table `object`:

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|  Field   |  Type   | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | INT(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| max_bids | INT(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and a table `bids`:

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|   Field   |  Type   | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | INT(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| object_id | INT(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to select all those objects which haven't reached their the maximum amount of bids. So an object with `bid_max` of 10 and only 5 bids should be in the result set of the query. An object with `bid_max` set on 2 and 2 bids must not appear.

I've a query, but this query allows only to have a static amount of bids. This query selects all object which have less than 3 bids:

```
SELECT object.id, COUNT(bid.object_id) FROM (bid INNER JOIN object ON bid.object_id = object.id) GROUP BY object.id HAVING COUNT(bid.object_id) < 3;
```

But the maximum amount of bids depends on the object. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select o.id, o.max_bids, count(b.id) as num_bids
  from objects o
  join bids b
    on o.id = b.object_id
 group by o.id, o.max_bids
having count(b.id) < o.max_bids
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're loking for:

```
SELECT 
    o.id, 
    COUNT(b.object_id) 
FROM bid b
JOIN object o ON b.object_id = o.id
GROUP BY o.id 
HAVING COUNT(b.object_id) < o.bids;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that some objects don't have any bids yet, then you want a `left join`:

```
SELECT o.id, COUNT(b.id)
FROM object o LEFT JOIN
     bid b 
     ON b.object_id = o.id
GROUP BY o.id, o.max_bids
HAVING COUNT(b.id) < o.max_bids;
```